# How to set mysql Default value NONE

Tags: mysql, default-value

I am using a table  "media_content" which has columns

```
id varchar(50) NOT NULL,
shorttitle varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
sourceimage blob
```

Later i modified the sourceimage column to  default values as `NULL`

```
ALTER TABLE media_content
MODIFY COLUMN sourceimage VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Now i want to make the `sourceimage` column default as `NONE`,  is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the default value (of a string-type column) to be a string literal constant, such as `'NONE'`, but be aware that such a value has a very different meaning indeed to `NULL` (which indicates no value at all).

As documented under [Working with `NULL` Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/working-with-null.html):

> The `NULL` value can be surprising until you get used to it. Conceptually, `NULL` means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> A common error when working with `NULL` is to assume that it is not possible to insert a zero or an empty string into a column defined as `NOT NULL`, but this is not the case. These are in fact values, whereas `NULL` means “not having a value.”

If you merely wish to present `NULL` values to your users in some other way, you should handle that at the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the info @eggyal. You mean, let the Default value in the DB be NULL  and @ the service side if the value for sourceimage is NULL then handle it with some keywords.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same `ALTER` syntax, the default value can be changed to `NONE` as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE media_content
MODIFY COLUMN sourceimage VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT 'NONE';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue (and the relationship between `NULL || NOT NULL`, and default values) becomes clearer when you consider that:

`NOT NULL` ⇒ **REQUIRED**: there must either be a default value, or else record insertion without a specified value must not be allowed (specifying a default value, or selecting "None"⇒no default specified; might indicate your preference between these two options: the latter option meaning that insertion without a value in this field should be rejected with an error); whereas:

`NULL` ⇒ **NOT REQUIRED** — `NULL` signifies that *no value was specified* for a field, or, the value is unknown. (If a field is "NULLable", then it would be nonsense to try to say you don't want to specify the default value; since according to nullability, insertion is going to be allowed anyway even if you don't specify this field value! The field must therefore have a default: whether that is `NULL` or some specific value.)

If you are using phpMyAdmin, you should visit the Structure tab of the relevant table, find the relevant column definition, and select "Change". In the "Default" drop-down, you will see the option, "None": select that, and press "SAVE". Taking note of the SQL command this generates, you will see something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE  `…_tbl` CHANGE  `…_fld` `…_fld` TEXT NOT NULL;
```

HOWEVER, if we try to specify, in the user-interface, that the default should be "None" but that NULL should be allowed; then the default will instead revert to "" (empty string) or "0000-00-00 00:00:00" (in the case of a `DATETIME` field), etc. So the key here is whether the column (field) is `NULL`ABLE or not!

This "None" option may be partly an artefact of the abstraction used by phpMyAdmin to represent what's actually going on in the underlying database (which is something different).

Before changing your field to a `NOT NULL` type; first check the existing values, and make sure that they will be automatically changed in a way you approve.

In other words: `NULL` / `NOT NULL`, and default values; are essentially related to each other: user-interfaces that don't usefully represent this relationship by constraining the combinations of values you can specify, are ergonomically deficient. phpMyAdmin and perhaps other tools, could be improved in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think the original post is asking how to remove a default value, not add the string literal "none". If so, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE media_content ALTER COLUMN sourceimage DROP DEFAULT;
```